# How to enumerate nested data/keys with FirebaseLib?

Tags: php, firebase

Any ideas, why this code does not work? There are multiple nodes inside "names"

```
$online_users = json_decode($firebase->get(PATH . '/' . $users . '/names/') );     
     echo "$online_users";
     if ($online_users != null) {
         foreach ($online_users as $key => $value) {
             if ($value) {
                 echo "$key $value<br>";
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

json_decode will return null if it's not a json data, or an object (array if you add the option). Use json_last_error (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-last-error.php) if you have null to know what is the error.

You can't use echo "$online_users"; because echo need a string. But you may have an object. Choose print_r() or var_dump()